# ADC required for 24v i/p

Tags: adc

I need an ADC which can take up to 24v as analog i/p and convert into the digital o/p or binary o/p which i can fed into the micro controller.

Comment: this seems like an overly broad question. What speed do you need. Is this for industrial? What are the details we need to teach you how to pick this.

Comment: *the* microcontroller? which one? most modern microcontroller have A/D hardware on the chip, in which case the problem would be reduced to a resistor divider (see the answers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're stating the problem wrong; you don't want an ADC which can read 24V input, you want to read 24V input, by whatever means.
Almost all ADCs work at lower voltages, often 0V to 5V, or 0V to 3.3V for ADCs integrated in microcontrollers. So you'll have to lower the 24V to suit this range. The easiest way is to use a resistive voltage divider, like 8.2k\$\Omega\$ + 1.2k\$\Omega\$, which will scale your 24V to 3.13V.
ADC inputs often have a rather low input impedance, and thus may distort the resistor divider's ratio. This can be taken care of by using a voltage follower as buffer:

[image: voltage follower]

Comment: I would bet a couple resistors can be saved by using an industrial ADC. I would guess that a 0-24V range is industrial and their may be some transients and such to worry about. I agree that a resistive divider is an easy way to use one already on hand and a good idea.

Comment: i need to store real time values of an circuit output which varies from 5v to 24 v in a micro controller 8051 but my prob is as micro controller takes only digital values  i need to use an ADC to convert but the limitation of ADC s 5v what can i do to capture the real time values.

Comment: this project is for industrial purpose

Comment: @Rajath - what is the highest frequency of the input signal? (how quickly does it change?) What level of resolution is needed? (e.g. do you need to see millivolt changes?) Can you give us the actual 8051 part number you are using?

Answer (score 3):

Usually you scale your input voltage range to fit with your ADC range, rather than the other way round. Why not use a divider to give yourself a wider choice of ADC e.g. 1/8 so you end up with 0-3V. If the microcontroller has an ADC you will then be able to use that.
Knowing a little more about what it's needed for, the resolution needed and frequencies involved (how many samples per second needed) would help to give better advice.

EDIT - [here](http://uk.farnell.com/texas-instruments/tlc549cp/ic-8bit-adc-40ksps-pdip8-549/dp/8454361) is a very basic/cheap ADC picked at random to give an example.

[image: ADC example]

It is 8-bit, so will have 256 discrete steps between it's low reference voltage and high reference voltage. It takes around 40,000 samples a second maximum, so the highest frequency you will be able to "see" is about 20kHz, much lower for any meaningful representation of the signal.

The data is passed to the microcontroller serially using DATA-OUT, I/O CLOCK and CS. I have not read the datasheet, but probably you do *something like*: pull CS low, apply clock pulses to CLOCK I/O and the each bit from LSB to MSB will appear at DATA OUT.

If we assume you use 5V for your supply, and the high reference (REF+) is also the same 5V and low reference (REF-) is 0V, then the LSB (the smallest step of the digital values) will equal 5/256 ~= 19.5 mV. However you need to see up to 24V so this will not work without a divider to make the 0-24V fit into the 0-5V range of the ADC.

So we make a voltage divider using two resistors - the ratio between them is more important than the individual values, although a lower total value will sink more current and may load your source (the voltage you want to read) too much.
Anyway, 24/5 = 4.8, so lets pick 40k for R1 and 10k for R2 (formula is Vout = (Vin * R1+R2/R2))
Now your LSB value will be 24/256 = ~93mV
As a picture often helps explain these things better than words, here are a schematic and simulation of the results.

[image: Schematic]

Here are the results of applying a slowly rising voltage at Vin from 0V to 24V (blue is you r input voltage, green is the divided voltage and red is the same voltage buffered with an opamp for lower impedance to drive the ADC input) U1 could be just about any opamp (e.g. MCP6021 off the top of my head):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This leading comment will be deleted once the question is sortd out properly.This is the same answer that I just gave to your essentially identical other question. I suggest that you delete one or other question and update the other question to better reflect what you want to achieve.

**Divide the input voltage by about 5 to bring it to within the range of the ADC.**

eg

- 39 kohm from input voltage to ADC pin.
- 10 kohm from ADC pin to ground.

This will divide by 4.9
  (which is the same as multiplying by 10k/(10K+39k) = 1/4.9 = 0.204.

You can then adjust the values internally to correspond to the results that you see.

eg 24V gives 24 /4.9 = 4.898 Volt.

Multiply this internally by 4.9 to get the original value.